# R Scatter Plot Issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatter plot and when I run the code all I get is a single point to be displayed. My file name is: R_VonB_Nebish_SMB_Method1_2010_2015 , code is as follows;

```
ggplot(R_VonB_Nebish_SMB_Method1_2010_2015, aes(x ="SCALE.AGE", y ="ESTIMATE")) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Try this : `ggplot(R_VonB_Nebish_SMB_Method1_2010_2015, aes(x =SCALE.AGE, y =ESTIMAT")) +
  geom_point()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the columns as strings:

```
ggplot(R_VonB_Nebish_SMB_Method1_2010_2015, aes(x=SCALE.AGE, y=ESTIMATE)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you did differently? I am new to this R stuff.

Comment: I can just guess, but I think ggplot() internally creates objects from the different columns of the provided data.frame. These objects are refered to by their names. You provided a String object instead that can't be resolved.

Comment: It's definitely function/library specific. The way you approached it could have been correct for other functions.